# How to capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence?

Tags: php, regex, user-input, text-segmentation

I am trying to write a function to clean up user input.

I am not trying to make it perfect. I would rather have a few names and acronyms in lowercase than a full paragraph in uppercase.

I think the function should use regular expressions but I'm pretty bad with those and I need some help.

If the following expressions are followed by a letter, I want to make that letter uppercase.

```
 "."
 ". " (followed by a space)
 "!"
 "! " (followed by a space)
 "?"
 "? " (followed by a space)
```

Even better, the function could add a space after ".", "!" and "?" if those are followed by a letter.

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Offering realistic sample input and desired output are vital parts of creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
$output = preg_replace('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/e', "strtoupper('\\1 \\2')", ucfirst(strtolower($input)));
```

Since the modifier *e* is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', function ($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[2]);
}, ucfirst(strtolower($input)));
```

Comment: @w35l3y your code interest me... but How to do if my string is with some tags like that for example : `<span>hello.</span> this doesn' work !` ... ? can you improve your code please for this kind of case ? In fact, how to escape `<tags>` without delete them ? thank you :)

Comment: @Zagloo, in the case above, it is a requirement to have just 1 space independently of the current number of spaces. In your case, it is subject to a new question. Consider asking a new one and let me know. In short, I don't have good news for you because a `span` without any attribute is easy, but what about nested nodes with various attributes each?

Comment: @w35l3y Thx for your return ! I made a new post yesterday and someone found the solution  here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366592/php-improve-text-capitalization-function/29367216#29367216 ;o)

Comment: Hello. I don't understand the part  `[.!?] `of the regular expression. Isn't the unescaped dot expected to match ANY character (including "!" and "?")? I think it should be escaped but this answer has been here a lot of time...

Comment: @NeDark, in a `[]` block any character except `-^\]` is a literal.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code that does as you wanted:

```
<?php

$str = "paste your code! below. codepad will run it. are you sure?ok";

 
//capitalize first letter and every letter after a . ? and ! followed by space
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(?:^|[.!?]\h+\W*)\w/',
            function ($m) { return strtoupper($m[0]); }, $str);
 
// print the result
echo $str . "\n";
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Paste your code! Below. Codepad will run it. Are you sure?ok
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate string into arrays using `./!/?` as delimeter. Loop through each string and use `ucfirst(strtolower($currentString))`, and then join them again into one string.

Comment: Interesting take. I'll give it a try. I was hoping to practice my regex a little but this could get the job done. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
<?
$text = "abc. def! ghi? jkl.\n";
print $text;
$text = preg_replace("/([.!?]\s*\w)/e", "strtoupper('$1')", $text);
print $text;
?>

Output:
abc. def! ghi? jkl.
abc. Def! Ghi? Jkl.
```

Note that you do **not** have to escape .!? inside [].

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Without Regex.

```
$letters = array(
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
);
foreach ($letters as $letter) {
    $string = str_replace('. ' . $letter, '. ' . ucwords($letter), $string);
    $string = str_replace('? ' . $letter, '? ' . ucwords($letter), $string);
    $string = str_replace('! ' . $letter, '! ' . ucwords($letter), $string);
}
```

Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace('/([\.!\?]\s?\w)/e', "strtoupper('$1')", $input)
```

Comment: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead

Answer (score -2):

```
$Tasks=["monday"=>"maths","tuesday"=>"physics","wednesday"=>"chemistry"];

foreach($Tasks as $task=>$subject){

     echo "<b>".ucwords($task)."</b> : ".ucwords($subject)."<br/>";
}
```