# PHP - Improve text capitalization function

Tags: php, regex, capitalization

I have a function that capitalize string:

```
function capitalize_sentence($text)
    {
      $output =  preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', function ($matches) {
            return strtoupper($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[2]);
        }, ucfirst(strtolower($text)));
        return $output;
    }
```

When I have a simple string like that:

```
$text = 'hello. this works !';
var_dump($text);

$text = capitalize_sentence($text);
var_dump($text);die;
```

this works nice:

```
string 'hello.this works !' (length=18) 

string 'Hello. This works !' (length=19)
```

But in my code, sometimes, string looks like this (with some tags) :

```
$text = '<span>hello.</span> this <b>works</b> !';
var_dump($text);

$text = capitalize_sentence($text);
var_dump($text);die;
```

Which gives me this (as you can see, first words are not capitalized...):

```
string '<span>hello.</span> this <b>works</b> !' (length=39)

string '<span>hello.</span> this <b>works</b> !' (length=39)
```

How improve my code ? I need to "escape" `<tags>` without delete them but capitalize first word as in the first example....

I need output like this :

```
string '<span>Hello.</span> This <b>works</b> !' (length=39)
```

Thank you !

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I think you can't do it by regex. Write a small lexical analyser

Comment: @AvinashRaj : '<span>Hello.</span> This <b>works</b> !'

Comment: @tutankhamun how to do that ?

Comment: Please, don't forget to mention your sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ucSentence($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    $flagNeedUC = TRUE; // start of sentence flag
    $flagTag = FALSE;   // inside tag flag
    $endOfSentence = array('.', '!', '?');
    for ($ix = 0; $ix < $len; $ix += 1) {
        if ($flagTag) {
            if ('>' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve end tag
                $flagTag = FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            if (in_array($str{$ix}, $endOfSentence)) { // resolve end sentence
                $flagNeedUC = TRUE;
            } elseif ('<' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve start tag
                $flagTag = TRUE;
            } elseif (ctype_alpha($str{$ix}) && $flagNeedUC) { // resolve first char after sentence end
                $flagNeedUC = FALSE;
                $str{$ix} = strtoupper($str{$ix});
            }
        }
    }
    return $str;
}
echo ucSentence('<span><b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !');
```

It prints `<span><b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b>`

**UPDATE** *especially for @w35l3y :)*

I'm added passing attribute value. It recognizes several forms of attribute value which occurs in wild internet:
`<tag attr="value">`, `<tag attr='value'>` and `<tag attr=value attr=value>`

```
function ucSentence($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    $flagNeedUC = TRUE; // start of sentence flag
    $flagTag = FALSE;   // inside tag flag
    $stageAttr = FALSE;  // inside attribute value
    $endOfSentence = array('.', '!', '?');
    for ($ix = 0; $ix < $len; $ix += 1) {
        if ($flagTag) {
            if ($stageAttr) {
                if ('=' === $stageAttr) {
                    if ('"' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $stageAttr = '"';
                    } elseif ('\'' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $stageAttr = '\'';
                    } else {
                        $stageAttr = ' >';                        
                    }
                } elseif (strpos($stageAttr, $str{$ix}) !== FALSE) {
                    if ('>' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $flagTag = FALSE;
                    }
                    $stageAttr = FALSE;
                }
            } else {
                if ('>' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve end tag
                    $flagTag = FALSE;
                } elseif ('=' === $str{$ix}) {
                    $stageAttr = '=';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (in_array($str{$ix}, $endOfSentence)) { // resolve end sentence
                $flagNeedUC = TRUE;
            } elseif ('<' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve start tag
                $flagTag = TRUE;
            } elseif (ctype_alpha($str{$ix}) && $flagNeedUC) { // resolve first char after sentence end
                $flagNeedUC = FALSE;
                $str{$ix} = strtoupper($str{$ix});
            }
        }
    }
    return $str;
}

$testArr = array(
    '<span><b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test. <span title="jane <3 john"> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test! <span title="hover -> here"> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test <span title="jane <3 john"> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test? <span title="hover -> here"> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test <span title="hover -> here"> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test. <span title=\'hover -> here\'> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
    'test. <span title=jane<3john data=jane> <b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !',
);
foreach ($testArr as $num => $testStr) {
    printf("[%d] %s\n", $num, ucSentence($testStr));
}
```

It prints:

```
[0] <span><b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[1] Test. <span title="jane <3 john"> <b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[2] Test! <span title="hover -> here"> <b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[3] Test <span title="jane <3 john"> <b>hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[4] Test? <span title="hover -> here"> <b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[5] Test <span title="hover -> here"> <b>hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[6] Test. <span title='hover -> here'> <b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
[7] Test. <span title=jane<3john data=jane> <b>Hello. </b></span> This <b>works</b> !
```

Comment: @tutankhamun, what about `<span title="jane <3 john"><b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !` or `<span title="hover -> here"><b>hello. </b></span> this <b>works</b> !` ?

Comment: I think `<` and `>` must be changed to `&lt;` and `&gt;` entities in HTML. Or if you get it from wild internet you can escape it before and unescape after function call.

Comment: Hmm. Escaping is a bad way. Tags will be escaped too. Good way is additionally condition to around attribute values. I think there is no solution for a very bad html i. e.`<span title=hover -> here><b>hello. </b></span>` but browsers will dislike it too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this update where I added more conditions and changed the replacement a bit:

```
 $output =  preg_replace_callback('/((?:^|[.!?])(?:<[^>]*?>)?)(\s*)(\w)/', function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . $matches[2] . strtoupper($matches[3]);
    }, ucfirst(strtolower($text)));
```

It outputs `<span>Hello.</span> This <b>works</b> !`.

Comment: But I'm affraid regex is a bad solution for this problem. What about `'<span>hello. </span> this <b>works</b>!'` and
`' <span>hello.</span> <span>this <b>works</b> </span>!'`?

Comment: It clearly is an improvement of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5383786/157873, but I agreed with @tutankhamun as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence/5383786?noredirect=1#comment46931432_5383786

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly modified version of @tutankhamun that prevents capitalizing characters after periods in email addresses or URLs (or any other time there is no space after the end of sentence characters (. ! ?)

```
function sentenceCase($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);
    $flagNeedUC = TRUE; // start of sentence flag
    $flagTag = FALSE;   // inside tag flag
    $stageAttr = FALSE;  // inside attribute value
    $lastChar = NULL;
    $endOfSentence = array('.', '!', '?');
    for ($ix = 0; $ix < $len; $ix += 1) {
        if ($flagTag) {
            if ($stageAttr) {
                if ('=' === $stageAttr) {
                    if ('"' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $stageAttr = '"';
                    } elseif ('\'' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $stageAttr = '\'';
                    } else {
                        $stageAttr = ' >';
                    }
                } elseif (strpos($stageAttr, $str{$ix}) !== FALSE) {
                    if ('>' === $str{$ix}) {
                        $flagTag = FALSE;
                    }
                    $stageAttr = FALSE;
                }
            } else {
                if ('>' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve end tag
                    $flagTag = FALSE;
                } elseif ('=' === $str{$ix}) {
                    $stageAttr = '=';
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (in_array($str{$ix}, $endOfSentence)) { // resolve end sentence
                $flagNeedUC = TRUE;
            } elseif ('<' === $str{$ix}) { // resolve start tag
                $flagTag = TRUE;
            } elseif (ctype_alpha($str{$ix}) && $flagNeedUC) { // resolve first char after sentence end
                $flagNeedUC = FALSE;
                if (!in_array($lastChar, $endOfSentence)) $str{$ix} = strtoupper($str{$ix});
            }
        }
        $lastChar = $str{$ix};
    }
    return $str;
}
```