# Convert the first character to uppercase in every newlines in php

Tags: php

I have the following paragraph :

```
This is the first line.
this is the second line.
we live in Europe.
this is the fourth line.
```

I want to convert the first character to  `uppercase` in every newlines.

So the paragraph should look like this :

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
We live in Europe.
This is the fourth line.
```

So far, I am able to convert the first character to uppercase, but it converts first characters in every words not in newlines using the  `ucfirst()` and  `ucword()`

```
echo ucfirst($str);
```

Is there a way to solve this using  `ucfirst()` or  `preg_replace()` function ?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence

Comment: how are these paragraphs generated? You could probaby do this in CSS rather than PHP.

Answer (score 5):

How about this one?

```
$a = "This is the first line.\n\r
this is the second line.\n\r
we live in Europe.\n\r
this is the fourth line.";

$a = implode("\n", array_map("ucfirst", explode("\n", $a)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this.

```
<?php
$str = strtolower('This is the first line.
This is the second line.
We live in Europe.
This is the fourth line.');
$str = preg_replace_callback('~^\s*([a-z])~im', function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[1]); }, $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
We live in europe.
This is the fourth line.
```

The `i` modifier says we don't care about the case and the `m` says every line of the string is a new line for the `^`. This will capitalize the first letter of a line presuming it starts with an a-z.

Comment: `\i` modifier is not required there as you have already lower-cased the input. Besides we need to match and replace lower cased char only so its not required at all.

Comment: This discards any non-line-starting capitalization, though, which would not usually be appropriate. You can see the proper noun Europe was lower-cased, as would the pronoun I.

Comment: Can you phrase that differently @ChrisBaker, or provide an example not sure I'm following. Ulver I noted what the modifier does OP can use it or not. The lower casing I'm doing is to illustrate the usage.

Comment: Here an example: Output here: `We live in europe.` Expected output: `We live in Europe.`

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you mean now. The OP shouldn't run their string through the `strtolower`. This is just a regex example of how this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is:

```
    <?php

   function foo($paragraph){

        $parts = explode("\n", $paragraph);
        foreach ($parts as $key => $line) {  
            $line[0] = strtoupper($line[0]);
            $parts[$key] = $line;
        }

        return implode("\n", $parts);
    }

    $paragraph = "This is the first line.
    this is the second line.
    we live in Europe.
    this is the fourth line.";

    echo foo($paragraph);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the very first lower cased char of every line by upper case:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
            '/^\s*([a-z])/m',
            function($match) {
                return strtoupper($match[1]);
            },
            $str);
```