# Making the first letter of every sentence upper case using ucfirst

Tags: php, string, uppercase, ucfirst

I'm trying to make the first letter of every sentence to be upper case while keeping the punctuation marks. I have tried ucfirst, but it only makes the first letter of the string uppercase, and not every other sentences. How do I fix this?

```
$text = "yes. are you listening to me? huh?!"
$text = ucfirst($text);

echo $text;
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Yes. Are you listening to me? Huh?!"
```

**Actual Output:**

```
Yes. are you listening to me? huh?!"
```

Comment: the manual page for this very function has several user functions to do this

Comment: like this one http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php#86902

Comment: that manual sure is an amazing place

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ucfirstSentence($str){
     $str = ucfirst(strtolower($str));
     $str = preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', 
       create_function('$matches', 'return strtoupper($matches[0]);'), $str);
     return $str;
}
```