# PHP: How to capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence, including a set of non-ASCII values?

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

I found an answer here: [How to capitalize first letter of first word in a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383471/how-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-word-in-a-sentence) however, it doesn't work when the sentence starts with characters such as `"` or `«`.

The code found in the link above is:

```
$output = preg_replace('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/e', "strtoupper('\\1 \\2')", ucfirst(strtolower($input)));
```

Here's an example of the handling I need

```
$input  => «the first article title» 
$output => «The first article title»

$input  => « the first article title »
$output => « The first article title »

$input  => "être"
$output => "Étre"
```

The idea is to ignore any non alphabetic (not in [a-z, A-Z] + french characters) and apply to the first alphabetic one and the rest will remain the same as the input.

Comment: and what is the `$input` content? Show the input and the expected output

Comment: Update the question with Input => Output examples. It's impossible to understand that you want from the comments.

Comment: What about [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a limit so that only 1 character is replaced:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[a-z]/e', 'strtoupper("$0")', strtolower($input), 1);
```

Though you should be using `preg_replace_callback()` rather than the `/e` switch nowadays:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[a-z]/',
    function($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[0]); },
    strtolower($string),
    1
);
```

**EDIT**

After the scope creep of changing the question to require UTF8 handling:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\p{L}/u',
    function($matches) { return mb_strtoupper($matches[0]); },
    mb_strtolower($string),
    1
);
```

Comment: Hi, it works fine when it's not french characters. For example "être" as an input will output "êTre".

Comment: You have to love scope creep; you never mentioned non-ASCII characters in your original question

Comment: Hi, it returns empty string :-(

Comment: [It works perfectly well with all of your examples](https://3v4l.org/80FQK)

Comment: I can see, I am using php 5.3 that's why is not working. Please, any idea

Comment: Upgrade your PHP to a supported version: PHP5.3 has been end of life since 14 Aug 2014, and even PHP5.6 will only be supported for security patches after tomorrow

Comment: Hi, Mark, thanks for your help. Is there any way to work this out when it xhtml. I think that's what it causing the problem with **'/\p{L}/u'**.